# How to write a zip function from scratch

Tags: scala, tuples

How to write the zip function, which tuples corresponding elements in a list. I understand that zip is a built in function but I am trying to write it from scratch.

```
def zip[A,B](lst1: List[A], lst2: List[B]): List[(A, B)]
```

Test example would be:

```
test("zip test 1") {
assert(zip(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6)) == List((1,4), (2, 5), (3, 6)))
}
```

or strings as parameters:

```
test("zip test 2") {
assert(zip(List("hey", "code"), List("world", "scala")) ==
List(("hey", "world"), ("code", "scala")))
}
```

I tried this so far:

```
 def zip[A,B](lst1:List[A], lst2:List[B]):List[(A,B)] = (lst1,lst2) match{
    case Nil=> Nil
    case (h1::t1 :: h2 :: t2) =>zip(t1, t2)
 }
```

But I get a type mismatch error, and a immutability error.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This just seems to be a "gimme the code" question currently

Comment: I had the base cases done but I got stuck understanding the tuples..(xy._1  xy._2). I was trying to incorporate that without any success. I kept getting the same list back. My pairing must have been off..

Comment: Edit your question to include your attempt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If either list is empty, return the empty list. Otherwise, prepend the pair of heads to the zip of tails:

```
def zip[A, B](xs: List[A], ys: List[B]): List[(A, B)] =
  (xs, ys) match {
    case (Nil, _) => Nil
    case (_, Nil) => Nil
    case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => (x, y) :: zip(xs, ys)
  }
```

Augmenting to exploit tail recursion optimisation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This doesn't compile :p You need `List[(A, B)]` as a return type instead of `List[A, B]`. You can also group two first cases to `case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) => Nil`

Comment: @Łukasz now it does!

Comment: @Łukasz `case _ => Nil` will probably work too when in the last position.

Comment: @VictorMoroz Right, that's even better.